# Building a new container with mixed CMD and RUN command does not work

Tags: docker, containers

I am new in docker and I am learning how to build a new container. I faced an issue to build a container, inherited from Ubuntu. I want to install Python3 and some other packages on the Ubuntu container with proper messages, but it does not work. 
When I build a container with `Dockerfile` with:

```
FROM ubuntu
CMD echo "hello new Ubuntu"
RUN apt-get upgrade &&  apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 
CMD echo "installed python"
```

the call of the built Ubuntu with `docker run -it my_new_ubuntu` does not enter to the interactive mode and it only prints `installed python`, not even the "hello new Ubuntu".

Although, when I build a container with `Dockerfile` without any message:

```
FROM ubuntu RUN apt-get upgrade &&  apt-get update && apt-get install
-y python3
```

and call the built container with `docker run -it my_new_ubuntu`, it enters the Ubuntu root and I can call python. I am not sure why the first `Dockerfile` does not work. It seems that I cannot mix `RUN` and `CMD` commands together.
I appreciate any help or comment.

Answer (score 0):

[`RUN`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) specifies a command to run while building an image from your Dockerfile. You can have multiple `RUN` instructions, and each will apply to the image in the order specified.

[`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) specifies the default command the image has been instantiated into a container and started. If there are multiple `CMD` instructions, only the last one applies.

Comment: Why when I have both commands, the built container does work properly?

Comment: With your first Dockerfile, if it prints "installed python" it is "working" properly, at least it is doing exactly what is expected from your Dockerfile.

Comment: @Zeitounator, but as I mentioned in the question, when I call it with `-it` to run an interactive run, it does not work.

Comment: `the call of the built Ubuntu with "docker run -it my_new_ubuntu" does not enter to the interactive mode and it only prints "installed python"` => this is absolutely what is expected from your Dockerfile. It actually enters the interactive mode using a term, runs the command `echo "installed python"` and exists. If you want it to stay "alive", you need to override this single non lasting command (e.g `docker run -it my_new_ubuntu bash`)